# Getting null as a results when using Tasks

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, async-await, task

I am trying to call a async function in loop to spawn object. it doesn't work as I expected. Dictionary is giving errors about adding same item multiple times. I can't make the whole function async. Here is the code:

```
public Dictionary_String_Prop GeneratePlaceables(List<PropData> props, Prop parent = null)
{
    Dictionary_String_Prop temp = new Dictionary_String_Prop ();
    if(props == null)
    {
        Debugger.Log("PropdataList Empty: Returning Empty Dictionary");
        return temp;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < props.Count; i++)
    {
        var result = GameModeGame.Get().placeableDB[props[i].dataID].Prefab;
        PropData propData = props[i];
        result.InstantiateAsync(props[i].sTransform.Position(), props[i].sTransform.Rotation()).Completed += a => 
        { 
            Placeable p = a.Result.GetComponent<Placeable>();

            p.uniqueID = propData.uniqueID;
            p.State = propData.state;
            p.InitData();
            if(parent)
                p.SetParent(parent);
            else
                p.transform.SetParent(manager.transform);

            p.transform.localScale = propData.sTransform.Scale();

            p.children = GeneratePlaceables(propData.placeables, p);

            temp.DebugLog();
            temp.Add(p.uniqueID, p);
            manager.allProps.Add(p.uniqueID, p);
        };
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I also tried to save all the instantiation task into an array and then use Task.WaitAll() to wait for thread to finish and then return from function but it also throws errors.

Question:- How can I instantiate every object asynchronously before exiting loop?

Comment: What is `Dictionary_String_Prop` ?  Is it a threadsafe dictionary? (Like `ConcurrentDictionary`).  What is the prototype for `InstantiateAsync` ?

Comment: It's a serialised dictionary. I am not sure about thread safe. Maybe I should test with normal dictionary.

Comment: If `InstantiateAsync` is really async, then you aren't waiting for those tasks to be finished before existing the function.   Does this whole function really need to be async?

Comment: It is from Unity's API. 
`public static AsyncOperationHandle<GameObject> InstantiateAsync(object key, Transform parent = null, bool instantiateInWorldSpace = false, bool trackHandle = true)` its the whole syntax I copied from there website. Here is the [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.8/api/UnityEngine.AddressableAssets.Addressables.html) of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to review the documentation for async/await for C# : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Each `async` method needs a matching `await` in your code you are not awaiting the result of the task so....

```
result.InstantiateAsync(.....
```

Needs an await:

```
await result.InstantiateAsync(.....
```

But this has effects that you will need to make your function `async`:

```
public Dictionary_String_Prop GeneratePlaceables(List<PropData> props, Prop parent = null)
```

Needs changing to:

```
public async Task<Dictionary_String_Prop> GeneratePlaceables(List<PropData> props, Prop parent = null)
```

Any method calling `GeneratePlaceables` will also need an `await`: [Why use Async/await all the way down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808915/why-use-async-await-all-the-way-down)

---

If you can't make changes to your functions there is another method that where you can wait synchronously for the result:

```
Foo foo = GetFooAsync(...).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

So:

```
result.InstantiateAsync(....).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

This won't require the changes to the function etc...

Comment: I know I can use async and await but due to some reasons I can't change the function. Is there any other way to do it without async await?

Comment: Updated my answer to include a way to get the result without using await